# Event system in react

Tags: react.js, event-handling

## What I Want?

I want to make an event system in React that cuts back on unnecessary re-renders and stops props drilling.

## What I Did?

The code I came up with is the following:

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

const sourceList = {};

export const useBroadcast = <T>(name: string) => {
  // if the event is already registered, returns a fireEvent to emit the event
  if (sourceList[name]) {
    const fireEvent = (variable: T) => {
      // fire the event sending the variable to all the listeners
      sourceList[name].forEach(listener => {
        listener(variable);
      });
    }; 
    return { fireEvent };
  }

  //else register the event in the list and return the fireEvent
  sourceList[name] = [];
  const fireEvent = (variable: T) => {
    sourceList[name].forEach(listener => {
      listener(variable);
    });
  }; 
  return { fireEvent };
};


export const useSubscribe = (name: string, callbackfunction: (variable?: unknown) => void) => {
  // check if the event is already registered
  if (!sourceList[name]) {
    throw new Error("Event is not registered, use useBroadcast to register an event first");
  }

  // put the subscribe in useEffect and unsubscribe in its cleanup function to prevent multiple subscriptions on re-renders
  useEffect(()=>{
    sourceList[name].push(callbackfunction);
    return () => sourceList[name]=sourceList[name].filter(func=>func!==callbackfunction);}
    ,[]);

}
```

### useBroadcast

The component that will be the origin of the event will use this hook. The hook will return a function that can be used whenever the event occurs (either by user action or as a result of calculations or requests callbacks).

This hook takes a name for the event (e.g., `"toolbar.button.click"` or `"fetchdata.success"`) and a type for the variable passed to the firing function. This variable will then be passed to the subscribing component upon firing.

### useSubscribe

The subscribing component will use this hook and give it the event name and the function that will be called when that event is fired. This function will receive the variable passed to the firing function from the originating component.

## Why?

I realize that I can achieve the same functionality using Recoil or Redux, but I want to keep re-renders to an absolute minimum. I find that props drilling causes unnecessary re-renders along the way, and I don't like Recoil's "spooky action at a distance" way of also causing re-renders in the originating component.

## What I'm Asking

What are the downsides of using such a system, or why shouldn't I use this approach?

**P.S.**
I'm not an expert in React and it may be an anti-pattern for React, and I admit to using this question as a learning opportunity.